# ffmpeg combining three images into a looped video

Tags: ffmpeg

So I have three images that I need to combine into a 10 second video, I have searched around and in the end I came up with the following command, it is generating a video but not what I expected.

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i 20180627124135055101050.JPG -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -i 20180627124135057101052.JPG -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -vf framestep=4,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -c:v mpeg4 -t 10 video.mp4
```

It is currently generating a video of 12 seconds in length, but it is also only showing the first image, I have played around with the framerate option and the framestep option values but all change that I can see is in the length of the video, it never actually shows the images in the order I need them to display.  What I basically need as a result is a giff of the 3 images in the order image 1, image 2, image 3, image 2. But as a mp4 of 10 seconds long.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT 1**

So I have made some progress, I am now using the following command to get the correct video output, but now I need it to loop so the total video length can be 10 seconds

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 0.25 -i 20180627124135055101050.JPG  -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 0.25 -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 0.25 -i 20180627124135057101052.JPG -loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 0.25 -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0"  video.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out, the command I had to use to get this working was:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 0.16 -i 20180627124135055101050.JPG  -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 0.16 -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 0.16 -i 20180627124135057101052.JPG -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 0.16 -i 20180627124135056101051.JPG -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[v1],[v1]loop=20:32767:0"  video.mp4
```